# Regex to match pattern but exclude matches with certain word inside

Tags: python, regex

I checked all relevant questions but it seems that lookbehinds do not allow words needed in my pattern.
  So this is my question:

i need to match this pattern:

```
  word1.*word3
```

but don't match if there is word2 inside, such as:

```
  word1 word2 word3
```

Is there a way to do this with one-liner regex? I ve done this with 2 regexes but i find it kind of messy :)

Comment: Probably looking for `word1((?!word2).)*word3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [tempered dot](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
word1(?:(?!word2).)*?word3
                    ^ un-greedy
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJRiBu/2)

Inside non-capturing group, at each advance, negative lookahead should pass otherwise next immediate character isn't matched and whole prompt fails.

Answer (score 2):

Regex (look at @revo's answer for more detail):

```
word1(?:(?!word2).)*word3
```

This doesn't use `regex` but it should work:

```
if word1 in your_string and word3 in your_string:
    w1 = your_string.index(word1)
    w3 = your_string.index(word3)

    if word2 not in your_string[w1, w3 + len(word3) - 1]:
        print(your_string[w1, w3 + len(word3) - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, friend. taking this in mind, however i need a regex :)